# Wordpress widget input bar

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Been working on a wordpress plugin (I've been reading tutorials but they all speak in terms I don't quite understand), it's all part of the learning curve for me.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Server status Plugin
Plugin URI: http://minepress.co.uk
Description: Minepress is a site which allows users to start up a free Minecraft website   for their server. This plugin shows the server status
Version: 0.01
Author: Bradly Spicer
Author URI: http://minepress.co.uk
*/
?>
```

Thats obviously the shell, I want to make it so whatever people put into an input it will be put into this html:

```
[b]Server Status:[/b] [img]http://res.public-craft.com/hb.php?ip=YOUR_IP&port=YOUR_PORT&on=OPTIONAL_ONLINE_IMAGE&off=OPTIONAL_OFFLINE_IMAGE[/img]
```

I assume it would be along the lines of:

```
<h3>Server Status:</h4> <img = "http://res.public-craft.com/hb.php?ip=<?php $Ipaddress?>&port=<?php$Port?>&on=http://minepress.co.uk/images/on.png&off=http://minepress.co.uk/images/off.png"</img>
```

I don't really know how I'd incorporate it

Thanks guys

Forgot to mention I followed a tutorial before and came out with this:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

Class ServerStatus extends WP_Widget
{
    function ServerStatus()
    {

    }

    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        extract(   $args, EXTR_SKIP );
        $title = ( $instance['title']) ? $instance['title'] : 'Server Status';
        $body = ( $instance['body']) ? $instance['body'] : 'Server Status Body';
        ?>
        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
        <?php echo $before_title . $title . $after_title ?>
        <p><?php echo $body ?></p>


error_reporting(E_ALL);
add_action("widgets_init", array('Server_Status', 'register'));
class Widget_name {
  function control(){
    echo 'I am a control panel';
  }
  function widget($args){
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    echo $args['before_title'] . 'Your widget title' . $args['after_title'];
    echo 'I am your widget';
    echo $args['after_widget'];
  }
  function register(){
    register_sidebar_widget('Widget name', array('Server_Status', 'widget'));
    register_widget_control('Widget name', array('Server_Status', 'control'));
  }
}

add_option($name, $value);
update_option($name, $new_value);
delete_option($name);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
add_action("widgets_init", array('Server_Status', 'register'));
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('Server_Status', 'activate'));
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array('Server_Status', 'deactivate'));
class Widget_name {
  function activate(){
    $data = array( 'option1' => 'Default value' ,'option2' => 55);
    if ( ! get_option('Server_Status')){
      add_option('Server_Status' , $data);
    } else {
      update_option('Server_Status' , $data);
    }
  }
  function deactivate(){
    delete_option('widget_name');
  }
  function control(){
    echo 'I am a control panel';
  }
  function widget($args){
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    echo $args['before_title'] . 'Your widget title' . $args['after_title'];
    echo 'I am your widget';
    echo $args['after_widget'];
  }
  function register(){
    register_sidebar_widget('Widget name', array('Server_Status', 'widget'));
    register_widget_control('Widget name', array('Server_Status', 'control'));
  }
}


function control(){
  $data = get_option('Server_Status');
  ?>
  <p><label>Option 1<input name="Server_Status_option1"
type="text" value="<?php echo $data['option1']; ?>" /></label></p>
  <p><label>Option 2<input name="Server_Status_option2"
type="text" value="<?php echo $data['option2']; ?>" /></label></p>
  <?php
   if (isset($_POST['widget_name_option1'])){
    $data['option1'] = attribute_escape($_POST['Server_Status_option1']);
    $data['option2'] = attribute_escape($_POST['Server_Status_option2']);
    update_option('Server_Status', $data);
  }
}
```

Goal: the goal is to make it so the user in the admin panel inputs their server ip and port (Two seperate input fields). These are then called and put into either of the scripts above. I assume it would be

```
<h3>Server Status:</h4> <img = "http://res.public-craft.com/hb.php?ip=<?php $Ipaddress?>&port=<?php$Port?>&on=http://minepress.co.uk/images/on.png&off=http://minepress.co.uk/images/off.png"</img>
```

But I don't know how to make the $Ipaddress and $Port to be whatever they input.

Comment: I hate it when people are anonymously voting down, so I will tell you what the stranger is pointing at.
The question doesn't seem clear to me. What are you asking? Can you be more clear about what you are trying to build, what you made, what errors you got (if you got any), how think you should have solved it but why it doesn't work. Etc. etc. Please provide us some more information. And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks for your words Jelmer, Yea I've been downvoted on it wrongly I think. I just updated the post with a better explanation I think :)

Comment: "a tutorial" can you provide us with an url to this specific tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses Jelmer, The tutorial I am following is:

http://valums.com/create-wordpress-widget/

Comment: Okay, from here on I pass the topic to someone else. I have 0 experience with WP, I hate Wordpress, I really do. So I can't help you with this. But I hope this cleared some details for other people. I will upvote it for your effort.

Comment: Thank you very much Jelmer you've been very helpful